# What is most simple eukaryotic genome?

Tags: biochemistry, dna, bioinformatics, eukaryotic-cells

Expressed in number of Base Pairs or Bytes, about how large is the simplest eukaryotic genome?

How much of this is 'junk-DNA' (non-coding)?

Comment: what do you mean by "most simple DNA molecule"?

Comment: you can synthesize DNA of any length, from 1 bp on up, so this question is kind of meaningless...

Comment: True.. but I implied that I wanted to know about the shortest naturally occurring DNA in eukaryotic cells.

Comment: Information content in mathematical sense?

Comment: I have to agree with @MattDMo, this question is meaningless in its current state (which is why I downvoted it and voted to close it). The problem would be much better if you were to clarify a few things. For example, what do you mean by "most simple DNA molecule"? Are you using the term "information" in the vernacular sense or in the theoretical sense? And if by "exists today" you really meant, "naturally occurring in eukaryotic cells", then it's better to say what you really mean. Addressing these concerns will help us as a community address your question meaningfully.

Comment: In case you were unaware, you can (and are encouraged!) go back and edit the text of your original question. We're not trying to condemn you for the way you asked the question, just providing suggestions for how you can clarify and improve the question, for your benefit and ours.

Comment: Hey @AndreasHartmann I've edited your question - hope this helps - feel free to change it again... thought this might help.  Most biologists don't think in terms of information content, which is not well defined beyond the 'one base = 2 bits' chestnut.

Comment: When you say genome, what exactly do you mean? All of the chromosomes? Biggest chromosome? Does mitochondrial or plastid DNA count? Do plasmids count?

Comment: How do you define simplicity? Because of what was discovered by the field of epigenetics, it is very difficult to figure out the exact entropy of a genome. @shigeta 's "times 2" model is only relevant for storage of sequence in a computer, not actual organisms.

Comment: You should edit your question to ask for the smallest eukaryotic genome, and maybe also ask for how compactness (% of coding sequence - junk DNA is a very obsolete term) varies with length. Everything else should be a separate question (which you can formulate after pondering your answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked about eukaryotes. The genome of the yeast *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* is 12.2 Mb.

The genome of the smallest free-living eukaryote, *Ostreococcus tauri* (a unicellular green alga) [is 12.6 Mb](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/31/11647.abstract)

There are smaller eukaryotic genomes, but these are not free-living organisms they are intracellular parasites.

Comment: I'd be interested in some detail about why Saccharomyces is not 'free-living' and maybe a reference for what the smaller genomes are?

Comment: @Shigeta the question was ambiguous, and my answer didn't help. O. tauri is physically (i.e. cell size) the smallest free-living eukaryote. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequenced_eukaryotic_genomes for some genomes of obligate intracellular parasites such as Cryptosporidium.

Answer (score -1):

According to this:
http://users.rcn.com/jkimball.ma.ultranet/BiologyPages/G/GenomeSizes.html
The shortest DNA of a individually living cell is that of Mycoplasma genitalium at about 580000 base pairs. -But it's not eucariotic!

Comment: ...but M. genitalium is not a eukaryote!